# Angular 9 - How to force re-render of component from within directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, inplace-editing

So I tried to implement inplace-edit on any input using attribute directive in angular 9 (using Ivy if that matters).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inline-edit-qwb2bg?file=src/app/inplace-edit/inplace-edit.directive.ts

The idea is that I can take any component and change appearance from directive. The problem is that I don't know how to revert to original intact appearance :-) So when I click on text - that text should be changed to simple input.
Tried so many approaches - nothing worked for me.

Well, there is a working approach with wrapping component into some other component and using ngIf with ngTemplateOutlet, but I want some cleaner solution - smth like in old good jQuery editinplace pluging - just to change behaviour and appearance of any component...

So in general the question is: if attribute directives can be used to alter appearance and behaviour of component, what should be done to fire re-render of component so it will appear as if no directive was applied to it?..

Comment: some time ago, Netanel Basal wrote about edit in place, take a look to https://netbasal.com/keeping-it-simple-implementing-edit-in-place-in-angular-4fd92c4dfc70 for inspiration

Comment: I saw that article and even mentioned that approach in my question, but I want to know about generic approach to re-rendering components. And I don't like writing the same html code over and over (which is html of editable component in Basal's approach)